# sharing one instance of a hashmap between all instances of spring service class

Tags: java, spring, real-time

I intend to create a realtime counter. So one user can incremenet the counter value for specific key. Whilst another gets the updated count value via an ajax request (either in a loop, or using some long polling method). I will use a spring controller, which will inject the service class can I do something like below, or is there a better way :

```
@Service
public MyService{

//instance variable in spring injected service class, not sure if this correct
static final Map<String, Integer> myMap;


public void add(String key){
  Integer count = myMap.get(key);
  count++;
  myMap.put(key, count);
}

//accessed via ajax loop (and controller), if value changes update display
public Integer getCount(String key){
  return myMap.get(key)
}

@PostConstruct
public load(){
  myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(10){{//initialize}};
}
```

**Edit** there are a few answers but it is not clear which is the best : Synchronize the add method ? Create map in another class(annotated repository) and inject that ? Something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but need to be aware of those problems:

- the map is empty initially, but you never check for null counters;
- the add() method doesn't modify the counter in the map. You need to put the counter back in the map after incrementing it, since Integer is immutable. Or you need to store mutable counters inside the map
- several threads are accessing the map without any kind of synchronization, which will lead to bugs, erratic behavior, or exceptions
- this strategy will obviously fail in case your app is clustered among several servers

Comment: I have edited out the minor probs, but what is the best way to solve "several threads are accessing the map without any kind of synchronization, which will lead to bugs, erratic behavior, or exceptions"

Comment: In a real application, there is more than the main thread that can access to your shared resources (specially in Web Applications), so one thead can put object A with "key" key, while another thread will insert object B with "key" key at the same time. In case of map, you can use [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to manage these issues.

Comment: *Correct* usage of a ConcurrentMap storing AtomicInteger instances is a solution. But you really need to understand all the potential threading issues before implementing anything. Read *Java Concurrency in Practice*.

Comment: @JBNizet I can't just create a class to wrap the map, annotate as repository and inject that ?

Comment: Yes, you can, as I said in my answer. But since the bean will be accessed by multiple threads, you must make it thread-safe and correct.

Comment: @JBNizet OK, how about this :http://stackoverflow.com/q/11126684/106261 thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 0):

Use ConcurrentHashMap

```
public void add(String key){
    Integer count = myMap.get(key);
    count= count++;
    myMap.put(key, count);
}
```

Comment: This is still incorrect code. It doesn't have any synchronization issue, but you might have three threads call the add method cocurrently, and have the value incremented by 1 only.

Comment: yes you are correct. have to make the method synchronized I think?

Comment: That's a way to make the code correct, provided the other methods accessing the map are also synchronized. But if this is done, using ConcurrentMap doesn't have any advantage over using a simple HashMap.

Comment: synchronizing service method is something we have to avoid

Comment: How about a one liner? ```myMap.put(key, myMap.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1)```. Might still need to confirm internal implementation to confirm same thread can access the read and write locks on intended segment simultaneously (like re-entrant locks).

Answer (score 0):

The `Integer` class is **immutable**.  This means that you can't make modifications to it.  So, in order to increment the count, you have to put it *back* into the map after you've incremented it:

```
public void add(String key){
  Integer count = myMap.get(key);
  count++;
  myMap.put(key, count);
}
```

A problem that this introduces is **thread safety**.  If this service class is going to be accessed by multiple threads at the same time, then you have to make sure its data is accessed in a safe way.  Since the `myMap` is being modified, and because the `HashMap` class is not thread-safe, you have to make it thread-safe.  One way you can do this is to use the `Collections.synchronizedMap()` method.  This will automatically make a Map instance thread-safe.

```
@PostConstruct
public load(){
  myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(10){{//initialize}};
  myMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);
}
```

Comment: It will make the `Map` thread safe, but the non-atomic `add()` method is still not thread safe.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Oh yeah, that's true.  You would have to make the `add()` method synchronized or wrap its body in a `synchronized(myMap)` block.