# Using ConcurentHashMap and AtomicInteger as instance variables within a spring service class

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency

I am attempting to implement thread-safe usage of ConcurentHashMap within singleton spring service that is injected into controllers:

```
@Service
public MyService{

  final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,   AtomicInteger>(10) {
        {/* initialize the ten key/values */
        }
    };

 public int add(String key) {
   return myMap.get(key).incrementAndGet();
 }

    // accessed via ajax loop (and controller), if value changes update display
  public int getCount(String key) {
    return myMap.get(key).get();
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to make access to a hashmap thread-safe?  How could I adapt this to work in a clustered environment? It is a follw up to [my other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11125497/106261)

Comment: Have you looked at Guava's [`ConcurrentHashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html), which does basically exactly this thing?  If you don't want the extra import, you can at least look at the source...

Comment: Just to confirm my undestanding..... Is "clustered" means multiple servers?

Comment: @J-16SDiZ yeah I am thinking in a tomcat/spring web environment, tbh I more interested in the best way to get thread safety in spring service classes

Comment: If you want to work across multiple servers, you need services like `memcached`. It have atomic `incr` / `decr` command.

Comment: Do you really _only_ have "read" access via AJAX? If so, the thread-safety is already there, isn't it? Or, more importantly, how `add` is called?

Comment: @nobeh add will also be called by ajax via a controller that has the service class injected

Comment: The above code is thread-safe and correct. Making it work in a clustered environment would indeed need a centralized server, cache or database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not aim to have an answer for the question esp. because I do not have expertise in the clustered situation; however, I'd like to point out what I think is worth noticing.

@JB Nizet in one of the comments mentions that the code is *thread-safe* and *correct*. I would like to add but *not consistent* based on [Java API Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove)

It means that there can be a client getting this information while some update is *currently* running. And, that makes sense since you mention 'looping' in your code. So, if this is **NOT** important in your case, then everything should be just fine.

But, if you need to make this more strict, I was thinking maybe using an instance of [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) would be a good choice. The lock enables your code to block all the read requests until there is a *consistent* snapshot of the information available. You'd be probably using the lock on the `getCount` method to strictly block until `add` method frees all the locks waiting for the consistent snapshot of the map used in the code.

I also have a guess that the same concern is valid when you migrate this to a clustered solution; if *consistency* is required across different cluster nodes, then it should be taken care of.

Comment: The `get` listed in the OP's answer is a get for the `AtomicInteger` and *not* the `ConcurrentHashMap`. So everything the OP is listing in his answer is thread-safe and cosisntent.